# Can Beehive Framework run on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, weblogic, beehive

We're looking to do a migration of an old app to cloud. Currently it is built on Beehive framework and running on Weblogic 10.3.6. My question is, can we run Beehive framework on tomcat and get rid of weblogic altogether? I can not find anything on this subject anywhere. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Beehive is coming from the Apache Foundation and is completly open source. Read the [documentation](https://beehive.apache.org/). Migrating your application from WebLogic Server to Apache tomcat should be possible.
It is a very old, deprecated and abandoned project. No fix or development since 2006. I suggest you to migrate your application to a more recent and powerfull JEE web framework if possible.